# ReactJs - Creating an "If" component... a good idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read in the React docs that "if" type statements can't be used in JSX code, because of the way JSX renders into javascript, it doesn't work out as one would expect.

But is there any reason why implementing an "if" component is a bad idea? It seems to work fine from my initial tests, and makes me wonder why this isn't done more often?

Part of my intent is to allow react development to be as much as possible, markup based - with as little javascript as possible. This approach, to me, feels like more of a "data driven" approach.

You can [check it out here on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/074ptfpq/7/)

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.11.0/dist/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.11.0/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */
    
var If = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'If',

  render: function()
  {
    if (this.props.condition)
      return <span>{this.props.children}</span>
    return null;
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
           <div>
             <If condition={false}>
                <div>Never showing false item</div>
             </If>
             <If condition={true}>
                <div>Showing true item</div>
             </If>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Main/>, document.body);
</script>
```

Running the above results in:

> Showing true item

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have conditional elements and keep DRY with Facebook React's JSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538638/how-to-have-conditional-elements-and-keep-dry-with-facebook-reacts-jsx)

Comment: This is actually asked from time to time when people start with React, but after they've been using it for a few weeks they stop wanting this.  Just use ternaries or `&&` to conditionally render things as mentioned in the other question.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the feedback.... I've been using the approach of conditionally rendering to a variable, then putting that variable in my `render` response, and it's been working fine. The thing with this approach is that it breaks up the JSX and makes it hard to see the full structure of the HTML in my responses. That's why I thought maybe an `If` component might help in those cases, and it does - the full markup of a response is easier to see in those circumstances - but i never realized the ternary approach/inline conditionals, and will probably use one of those instead.

Comment: and for what it's worth, i think this question should stay open, as I think this will come up in searches more, and there's some great, detailed  answers already added to this discussion that I haven't seen anywhere else!

Comment: Yeah, I understand the rationale.  I thought the same thing at first.  -- btw, closed questions often get a lot of traffic on google, but yeah, if anything the other question should be closed to point to this one.

Comment: Instead of returning `<noscript/>`, prefer returning `null` which is possible since React 0.11.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Check out the [If-Else in JSX](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html) section in the react Docs.

In JSX, you can't put statements inside curly braces--only expressions.  If you don't know the difference between expressions vs statements in JavaScript read this [article](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html). This limitation is because JSX desugars  into function calls and you can't use if-statements as arguments to a function in JavaScript. However, you can use boolean operators (`&&`, `||` and `? :`) to do a similar job. They are expressions so they can fit inside the constructor calls JSX generates and their short-circuiting evaluation is the same as the one used in if statements.

```
<div>
    {(true
        ? <div>Showing true item</div>     
        : <div>Never showing false item</div>
    )}
</div>
<p>My name is {this.name || "default name"}</p>
```

Additionally, React will treat `null` and `false` as an "empty component" that does not get rendered in the real DOM (currently it uses that same noscript trick behind the scenes). This is useful when you don't want an "else" branch. See [False in JSX](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/false-in-jsx.html) for details.

```
<div>
    {shouldIncludeChild ? <ChildComponent/> : false}
</div>
```

---

As for the If component you asked about, one problem it has is that in its current form it will evaluate its children even if the condition is false. This can lead to errors when the body of the If only makes sense if the condition is true:

```
<If condition={person !== null}>
    //This code throws an exception if this.person is null
    <div>{person.name}</div>
</If>
```

You could workaround this by having the if component receive the body as a function instead of as a list of child components but its more verbose:

```
<If condition={person !== null} body={function(){
    return <div>{person.name}</div>
}/>
```

Finally, since the If component is stateless, you should consider using a plain function instead of a new component class, as this would make the "If" transparent to React's reconciliation algorithm. If you use an If component, then a `<div>` and a `<If><div>` will be considered incompatible and React will do a full redraw instead of trying to merge the new component with the old one.

```
// This custom if function is for purely illustrative purposes
// However, this idea of using callbacks to represent block of code
// is useful for defining your own control flow operators in other circumstances.
function myCustomIf(condition, onTrue, onFalse){
    onTrue  = onTrue  || function(){ return null }        
    onFalse = onFalse || function(){ return null }
    if(condition){
        return onTrue();
    }else{
        return onFalse();
    }
}

<div>    
    {myCustomIf(person !== null, function(){
         return <div>{person.name}</div>
     })}
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this with ES2015: https://gist.github.com/Ginhing/58305312a75f7f6d6165bb583ecc94ba

Comment: The "fat arrow" function syntax makes myCustomIf easier to use but I would rather just use the built-in `?:` instead.

Comment: This barely answers the question though.

Comment: But if you are using redux you can make your parent component not aware of condition you are checking when you connect If component in redux creating some container. So you can create container AppWasLoaded basing on If container by mapping state to test `condition` property. Wouldn't it be a good idea in such case to have If and use it to create more specific containers?

Answer (score 36):

You don't need anything than plain JS.

## Safe and readable (but verbose)

```
maybeRenderPerson: function() {
    var personName = ...;
    if ( personName ) {
        return <div className="person">{personName}</div>;
    }
}

render: function() {
    return (
       <div className="component">
          {this.maybeRenderPerson()}
       </div>
    );
}
```

It is a bit verbose, but it permits to easily split your logic in smaller, focused blocks. When components start to become complex, this is the most readable.

---

## Concise and readable (but dangerous)

```
render: function() {
    var personName = ...; // present or absent name, but never ""
    return (
       <div className="component">
          {personName && (
            <div className="person">{personName}</div>
          )}
       </div>
    );
}
```

This syntax can be quite dangerous if the tested variable can be falsy values like `0`,`""` or `false`. Particularly with numbers you should rather modify the test slightly if you want to make sure it renders for 0:

```
render: function() {
    var counter= ...; // number, can be 0
    return (
       <div className="component">
          {(typeof counter !== 'undefined') && (
            <div className="counter">{counter}</div>
          )}
       </div>
    );
}
```

When components become complex, splitting into multiple smaller components, and having code-style conventions can help to keep it readable:

```
render: function() {
    var person= ...; 
    var counter= ...; 
    return (
       <div className="component">
          {person && (
            <Person person={person}/>
          )}
          {(typeof counter !== 'undefined') && (
            <Counter value={counter}/>
          )}
       </div>
    );
}
```

---

## Modern syntax (but too early)

The `do` notation with functional stateless components can be useful for expressiveness without loosing readability. You can easily split a large component into very small and focused ones that use the `do` notation:

```
const Users = ({users}) => (
  <div>
    {users.map(user =>
      <User key={user.id} user={user}/>
    )}
  </div>
)  

const UserList = ({users}) => do {
  if (!users) <div>Loading</div>
  else if (!users.length) <div>Empty</div>
  else <Users users={users}/>
}
```

It is a bit like using the module pattern inside JSX, so it's quite flexible, but with a lot less boilerplate.

To enable this, you need ES7 stage 0 compilation tooling, and support from your favorite IDE might not exist yet.

Comment: By far the most accurate answer I've read because it's super idiomatic. Nice idea.

Comment: I agree this is definitely nice and clean... And adding more functions can improve readability and help with call stack tracing and dumping too!

Comment: I have found this way to be ideal for anything but the simplest conditional check, and is great when choosing between many different React components (i.e. implement a switch statement).

Comment: That's ES7 example is really cool! You can use the same pattern with ES6 by removing the `do` adding a three `return` statements.

Answer (score 16):

You can do inline conditionals like this

```
{true && (
<div>render item</div>
)}

{false && (
<div>don't render item</div>
)}
```

Or you can just use a var

```
var something;

if (true) {
something = <div>render item</div>
}

{something}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do a self-executing function, with the right context too (with the help of Babel though)! Which I prefer because there's no need for assigning of variables and you can be as complex as you want (though you probably shouldn't for the sake of maintainability):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Hello!</div>
      {() => {
        if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
          return <Dashboard />
        } else {
          return <SignIn />
        }
      }()}
      <div>Another Tag</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The experimental ES7 `do` syntax is really nice for this situation. If you're using Babel, enable the `es7.doExpressions` feature then:

```
render() {
  var condition = false;

  return (
    <div>
      {do {
        if (condition) {
          <span>Truthy!</span>;
        } else {
          <span>Not truthy.</span>;
        }
      }}
    </div>
  );
}
```

See http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:do_expressions

Answer (score 4):

I think your main question is not "Can I implement an **If** component" (because clearly you can), but "Is there any reason why implementing an **If** component is a bad idea?"

The main reason it's a bad idea is because an adds component render cycles to what would otherwise be a small amount of code in an existing component. The extra component wrapper means that React needs to run an entire extra render cycle on its children. This is not a big deal if the **If** component is only used in one place, but if your app is littered with them, you've just made your UI that much slower.

Similar to how: `<div>Hi</div>` is more efficient than `<div><div>Hi</div></div>`.

Comment: perfect answer. rest all are showing off their react skills

Answer (score 2):

ES7 `do` closure is great for that:

For example, if you're using `webpack` - you can add ES7 features:

Firstly install `stage-0` features with:

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 -save-dev;
```

Then in webpack loaders settings, add stage-0 babel preset:

```
    loaders : [
        //...
        {
            test : /\.js$/,
            loader : "babel-loader",
            exclude : /node_modules/,
            query : {
                presets : ["react", "stage-0", "es2015"]
            }
        }
    ]
```

Then your component render function can look like:

```
import React , { Component } from "react";

class ComponentWithIfs extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="my-element">
                {
                    do {
                        if ( this.state.something ) {
                            <div>First Case</div>
                        } else {
                            <div>2nd Case</div>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the case. I just had the same question that why I'm here. I just think that if the component to render is huge, it can be usefull to have an IF component instead of the standard conditional rendering method.

```
...
<IF condition={screenIs("xs")}>
       <div> Then statement</div>
       <div>other Statement</div>
       <div>and so on</div>
</IF>
...
```

is definitively more readable than

```
...
{
  screenIs("xs") &&  (
     <Fragment>
         <div> Then statement</div>
         <div>other Statement</div>
         <div>and so on</div>
      </Fragment>
    )
 }
 ...
```

also for ternary statement,

```
...
<IF.Ternary condition={screenIs("xs")}>
   <Fragment>
       <div> Then statement</div>
       <div>other then Statement</div>
       <div>and so on</div>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment>
       <div> Else statement</div>
       <div>other Else Statement</div>
       <div>and so on</div>
   </Fragment>
 </IF.Ternary>
 ...
```

is more readable than

```
...
{
  screenIs("xs")
   ? (
     <Fragment>
         <div> Then statement</div>
         <div>other Then Statement</div>
         <div>and so on</div>
      </Fragment>
    )
    : (
     <Fragment>
         <div> Else statement</div>
         <div>other Else Statement</div>
         <div>and so on</div>
      </Fragment>
    )
 }
 ...
```

anyway, to make it more readable, you can just define your conditional rendering part in some method and call it in your main render

```
{
  ...
  renderParts = () => {
    return screenIs('xs') ? <div>XS</div> : <div>Not XS</div>
  }
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      ...
      {this.renderParts()}
      ...
    )
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, I just released a [react module](https://github.com/gfdev/javascript-react-if-component) for these purposes:

```
var Node = require('react-if-comp');
...
React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Node if={false} else={<div>Never showing false item</div>} />
                <Node if={true} then={<div>Showing true item</div>} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid conditional rendering with "templates" altogether. In React and JSX you can use the [full set of JavaScript functionality to make conditional rendering](https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/) happen:

- if-else
- ternary
- logical &&
- switch case
- enums

That's what makes the rendering with JSX so powerful. Otherwise one could invent again own templating languages that are library/framework specific like in Angular 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

For maintainable code skip unnecessary abstractions like `If` and add some control logic with an *early termination* before the `return` statement in your `render` method, e.g.

```
import React from 'react-native';

let {
  Text
} = React;

let Main = React.createClass({
  setInitialState() {
    return { isShown: false }
  },
  render() {
    let content;
    if (this.state.isShown) {
      content = 'Showing true item'
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    return (
      <Text>{content}</Text>
    );
  }
});
```

Keeps you DRY. Lasting protection.

Answer (score 0):

[render-if](https://github.com/ajwhite/render-if) is a light weight function that will render an element if a condition is satisfied

#### As an in-line expression

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {renderIf(1 + 2 === 3)(
        <span>The universe is working</span>
      )}
    );
  }
}
```

#### As a named function

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const ifTheUniverseIsWorking = renderIf(1 + 2 === 3);
    return (
      {ifTheUniverseIsWorking(
        <span>The universe is still wroking</span>
      )}
    )
  }
}
```

#### As a composed function

```
const ifEven = number => renderIf(number % 2 === 0);
const ifOdd = number => renderIf(number % 2 !== 0);

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {ifEven(this.props.count)(
        <span>{this.props.count} is even</span>
      )}
      {ifOdd(this.props.count)(
        <span>{this.props.count} is odd</span>
      )}
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me is enough taking advantage of the lazy evaluation in a logic expression if no else statement is needed:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
             {
                 condition &&
                     <span>Displayed if condition is true</span>
             }
        </div>
    );    
}
```

Or the ternay operator if an else is needed:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
             {
                 condition ?
                     <span>Displayed if condition is true</span>
                          :
                     <span>Displayed if condition is false</span>
             }
        </div>
    );    
}
```