# How would I use React Hooks to replace my withAuth() HOC?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I've been spending a bunch of time reading up on React Hooks, and while the functionality seems more intuitive, readable, and concise than using classes with local state and lifecycle methods, I keep reading references to Hooks being a replacement for HOCs.

The primary HOC I have used in React apps is withAuth -- basically a function that checks to see if the currentUser (stored in Redux state) is authenticated, and if so, to render the wrapped component.

Here is an implementation of this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export default function withAuth(ComponentToBeRendered) {
  class Authenticate extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      if (this.props.isAuthenticated === false) {
        this.props.history.push("/signin");
      }
    }
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.isAuthenticated === false) {
        this.props.history.push("/signin");
      }
    }
    render() {
      return <ComponentToBeRendered {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { isAuthenticated: state.currentUser.isAuthenticated };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authenticate);
}
```

What I can't see is how I can replace this HOC with hooks, especially since hooks don't run until after the render method is called. That means I would not be able to use a hook on what would have formerly been ProtectedComponent (wrapped with withAuth) to determine whether to render it or not since it would already be rendered.

What is the new fancy hook way to handle this type of scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### render()

We can reframe the question of 'to render or not to render' a tiny bit. The render method will **always** be called before either hook-based callbacks or lifecycle methods. This holds except for some soon-to-be [deprecated lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting).

So instead, your render method (or functional component) has to handle all its possible states, including states that require nothing be rendered. Either that, or the job of rendering nothing can be lifted up to a parent component. It's the difference between:

```
const Child = (props) => props.yes && <div>Hi</div>;
// ...
<Parent>
  <Child yes={props.childYes} />
</Parent>
```

and

```
const Child = (props) => <div>Hi</div>;
// ...
<Parent>
  {props.childYes && <Child />}
</Parent>
```

Deciding which one of these to use is situational.

### Hooks

There are ways of using hooks to solve the same problems the HOCs do. I'd start with what the HOC offers; a way of accessing user data on the application state, and redirecting to `/signin` when the data signifies an invalid session. We can provide both of those things with hooks.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const mapState = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.currentUser.isAuthenticated
});

const MySecurePage = props => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(mapState);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        history.push("/signin");
      }
    },
    [isAuthenticated]
  );
  return isAuthenticated && <MyPage {...props} />;
};
```

A couple of things happening in the example above. We're using the `useSelector` hook from `react-redux` to access the the state just as we were previously doing using `connect`, only with much less code.

We're also using the value we get from `useSelector` to conditionally fire a side effect with the `useEffect` hook. By default the callback we pass to `useEffect` is called after each render. But here we also pass an array of the dependencies, which tells React we only want the effect to fire when a dependency changes (in addition to the first render, which always fires the effect). Thus we will be redirected when `isAuthenticated` starts out false, or becomes false.

While this example used a component definition, this works as a custom hook as well:

```
const mapState = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.currentUser.isAuthenticated
});

const useAuth = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(mapState);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        history.push("/signin");
      }
    },
    [isAuthenticated]
  );
  return isAuthenticated;
};

const MySecurePage = (props) => {
  return useAuth() && <MyPage {...props} />;
};
```

One last thing - you might wonder about doing something like this:

```
const AuthWrapper = (props) => useAuth() && props.children;
```

in order to be able to do things like this:

```
<AuthWrapper>
  <Sensitive />
  <View />
  <Elements />
</AuthWrapper>
```

You may well decide this last example is the approach for you, but I would [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25225016/11751077) before deciding.

Answer (score -1):

Building on the answer provided by *backtick*, this chunk of code should do what you're looking for:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const withAuth = (ComponentToBeRendered) => {
    const mapState = (state) => ({
        isAuthenticated: state.currentUser.isAuthenticated,
    });

    const Authenticate = (props) => {
        const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(mapState);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            props.history.push("/signin");
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated]);
        return isAuthenticated && <ComponentToBeRendered {...props} />;
    };
    return Authenticate;
};

export default withAuth;
```

You could render this in a container using React-Router-DOM as such:

```
import withAuth from "../hocs/withAuth"
import Component from "../components/Component"

// ...

<Route path='...' component={withAuth(Component)} />
```