# What is the equivalent to ng-if in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm coming to react from using angular and I'm trying to figure out a good react alternative to angular's ng-if directive where I render or dont render an element based on a condition. Take this code for example. I'm using typescript (tsx) btw but that shouldn't matter much.

```
"use strict";

import * as React from 'react';

interface MyProps {showMe: Boolean}
interface MyState {}

class Button extends React.Component <MyProps, MyState>{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render(){
    let button;
    if (this.props.showMe === true){
       button = (
        <button type="submit" className="btn nav-btn-red">SIGN UP</button>
      )
    } else {
      button = null;
    }
    return button;

}
}
export default Button;
```

This solution works, but is there another way that's generally used to achieve this effect? I'm just sort of guessing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28707437/957731

Comment: The method you have used is correct method in react. Using ternary operator will reduce your code to one line but logic will still be same. You can use null or blank string(only quotes) `''` when you don't want elements to be rendered.

Comment: The most recent official doc posted a few neat ways to do this. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 142, accepted):

How about [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)?

```
render() {
  return (
    this.props.showMe ? <button type="submit" className="btn nav-btn-red">SIGN UP</button> : null
  );
}
```

You can also use `&&`:

```
render() {
  return (
    this.props.showMe && <button type="submit" className="btn nav-btn-red">SIGN UP</button>
  );
}
```

Large block as in the comment can easily be handled by wrapping the JSX in `()`s:

```
render() {
  return this.props.showMe && (
    <div className="container">
      <button type="submit" className="btn nav-btn-red">
        SIGN UP
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also inline:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {this.props.showMe && <button type="submit" className="btn nav-btn-red">SIGN UP</button>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This answers my question

Comment: and how to use for larger blocks of code? just inline?

Comment: I also think it's quite okay but it still reminds me of the ugly PHP&HTML mixture

Comment: I miss Angular :(

Comment: I hope next framework will have better way to deal with conditional rendering. Already a good case for new framework

Comment: To me it is a lot cleaner than the endless ng hacks and when it is best to use which.  And I love being able to largely stay in the javascript-ish space personally.

Comment: It's not a solution cause the doesn't rerun itself when the data is updated unlike in angular or vuejs

Comment: @PatrickCyiza Can you elaborate on your problem? Sounds like shallow comparison issue.

Comment: I was mistaken because I was using react-native-router-flux and this library was acting kinda weird with rendering of inactive scenes. It actually caches them and don't rerender them when they active again. Sorry. Your solution was not the problem to my issue

Comment: In Vue.js you have the `v-if` and `v-show` directives, react seems uglier than Vue.js

Comment: It's just JSX syntax with a short-circuited conditional. Some people prefer JSX and others still like the HTML templates. There is no better  here. One is definitely NOT cleaner or more elegant than the other. It's all a matter of taste. Get down from your high horse React devs.

Comment: React is I believe, about constructing stuff yourself. I think it will not get harder even if you want to create more complex things. There's just less shortcuts, compared to Vue for eg

Comment: Thanks for telling me I can use NULL.

Comment: That's for "weird" things like that I love Angular... <3

Comment: This is the perfect demonstration of why React is great and elegant and all, but VueJS is that wherein the truly beautiful code lay. I love the philosophy behind React, love the simplicity of solving every problem with composition, but damn if them render functions aren't butttt ugly! One more time for the people in the back, VueJS took everything beautiful about angular js, made it more beautiful and also made it not perform like doggie doo doo. PS AngularX sucks dunno why anyone would use it, sorry big G, even fb has you here. @counterflow I'd love to see one of those jsx lovers try to art

Comment: I was forced by the client to use React and now Im having problem with these ugly react codes. I hope the client would have a change of mind and choose Angular instead.

Comment: @UdayHiwarale I still don't understand why everyone thinks react is better than Angluar. From my experience angular is way better than react...

Comment: Angular has a lot of files , fill hell that get me lost

Comment: it seems you can't use the return value from `&&` anymore, since a component must always return an `Element`: `'Main' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'false | Element' is not a valid JSX element.`

Answer (score 32):

**I am leaving this here for historical purposes, please see my edits below for a much better solution after having developed in react for a while**
<strike>I ended up creating an NgIf component (this is react native but probably works for react)</strike>

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class NgIf extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.show) {
      return (
        this.props.children
      );
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
}

export default NgIf;
```

Usage:

```
...
import NgIf from "./path/to/component"
...

class MyClass {
   render(){
      <NgIf show={this.props.show}><Text>This Gets Displayed</Text></NgIf>
   }
}
```

Im new to this so can probably be improved upon, but helps me in my transition from Angular

**EDIT**

*See edits below for a better explanation once I had more experience*

Thanks to Jay's Comment below, a great idea is also:

```
render() {
   <View>{this.props.value ? <Text>Yes</Text> : <Text>No</Text>}</View>
}
```

OR

```
render() {
   <View>{this.props.value && <Text>Yes</Text>}</View>
}
```

Similar to some of the other answers but works inline, instead of using the entire render block / function, doesn't require a special component, and you can use an else statement with the ternary operator. Plus items contained within the if statement don't throw an error if their parent object doesn't exist. Ie if if `props.value` doesn't exist, then `props.value.value2` won't throw an error.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152067

**EDIT 2:**

As per the above link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152067) and after a lot more experience developing react apps, the above way it not the best way to do things.

Conditional operators in react are actually very easy to get your head around. There are two ways to do things:

```
//Show if someItem
{someItem && displayThis}

//Show if else
{someItem ? displayThisIfTrue : displayThisIfFalse}
```

One caveat you might hit is if "someItem" isn't a boolean expression. If it is say 0 react will print a 0 or react native will give you an error about needing to wrap "0" in a text element. This usually isn't a problem for falsy tests, but will present an issue for truthy tests. For example:

```
{!someItem && displayThis} //Will work just fine if item is 0 or null or "" etc
{someItem && displayThis} //Will print the value of someItem if its not falsy
```

My often used trick? double negatives.

```
{!!someItem && displayThis}
```

Note that this does not apply to ternary operators *(myVar ? true : false)* since it implicitly converts the result into a boolean expression.

Comment: I like this the best. Using components and attributes to describe view logic.

Comment: **Update:** having looked at [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538638/), it appears this is unideal.

Comment: Being new to this myself, I agree, that looks like a good way to go. One drawback with my method that I have discovered is that it will still error out if an item contained within the NgIf object references something that does not exist. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I really appreciate that you updated it with time. It provides context, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for EDIT 2. My preferred solution

Answer (score 28):

If you have other elements too you can wrap just the conditional like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>Stuff</div>
    {this.props.showMe && (
      <button type="submit" className="btn nav-btn-red">SIGN UP</button>
    )}
    <div>More stuff</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not as clean as some of the other suggestions, but great for a one liner!

Answer (score 16):

I just wanted to add that `*ngIf` in angular does not instantiate the component that it is attached to. In React if you use an if statement within the `return` statement then it will still instantiate the component even though it isn't displayed. To achieve a true `*ngIf` type behavior in React you have to create a variable that holds the conditional component outside of the `return` statement:

```
render() {

  const show = false

  return show
     ? <AwesomeComponent />   //still instantiated
     : null
}

render() {

  let c = null
  const show = false

  if (show) {
    c = <AwesomeComponent />   //not instantiated
  }
  return c
}
```

Comment: I don't see the diff. it's exactly the same. Trenary is exactly the `if` section

Answer (score 12):

A bit nicer:

```
render() {
  return (
    this.props.showMe && <button type="submit" className="btn nav-btn-red">SIGN UP</button>
  );
}
```

Comment: hi i am trying to do this but I have several elements in one component and its not working

Answer (score 5):

I can think of at least three different ways to simulate ng-if functionality in React

- if
- switch
- IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression)

You can read the post here: [Angular's ng-if Equivalent In a React Component](https://angulartoreact.com/ng-if-react-equivalent/)

Basically, you want to do something like this:

```
var IfDemoComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var el = null;
    if (this.props.showMe) {
      el = (
        <div>
          I am only included in the DOM if this.props.showMe evaluates to true.
        </div>
      );
    }
   return el;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this completely unblocked me, saved the day! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

> `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `true` are valid children. They simply don’t
>   render. These JSX expressions will all render to the same thing:

So you can try this

```
const conditional=({condition,someArray})=>{
     return(
        <div>
          {condition && <Header /> // condition being boolean} 
          {someArray.length>0 && <Content />}
        </div>
      )
}
```

this can be useful to conditionally render React elements. This JSX only renders a  if condition is true 
and will render  only if someArray.length>0

Answer (score 5):

I do not like having many ternary operators in the code. That's why I made a library with a couple of useful components. "RcIf"

```
  <RcIf if={condition} >
    <h1>I no longer miss ngif</h1>
  </RcIf>
  <RcIf if={othercondition} >
    <h1>I no longer miss v-if</h1>
    <RcElse>
      <h1>I love react</h1>
    </RcElse>
  </RcIf>
```

You can install it from npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-if

Answer (score 4):

I am the creator of the Tersus-jsx.macro and I think this module provides exactly what is needed for this question.

Rather than mixing JSX expressions and ES6 to achieve ng-if or ng-repeat, this macro allows doing things the same way as in AngularJS for React JSX, e.g. for ng-if:

```
<div>
  <button
    tj-if={a === 0}
    id="gotoA"
    className="link"
    onClick={clicking}
  />
</div>
```

which is equivalent to

```
<div>
  {(a === 0) && (
    <button
      id="gotoA"
      className="link"
      onClick={clicking}
    />
  )}
</div>
```

Given that the latest version of create-react-app support Babel-Macro out of the box, all you need to do is npm install this module, wrap the render return with "tersus" and start assigning those props.

You can install this from:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tersus-jsx.macro

Comment: Great package !

Answer (score 3):

I'm coming from an angular background as well and was looking for a simple one liner to show the tag if the variable had any elements. This worked for me:

```
<div className="comic_creators">
    {c.creators.available > 0 ? <h4>Creators</h4> : null }
    {c.creators.items.map((creator,key) =>
        <Creator creator={creator} key={key}></Creator>
    )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

From React Documentation

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

```
function Mailbox(props) {
  const unreadMessages = props.unreadMessages;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      {unreadMessages.length > 0 &&
        <h2>
          You have {unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
        </h2>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const messages = ['React', 'Re: React', 'Re:Re: React'];
ReactDOM.render(
  <Mailbox unreadMessages={messages} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like using getters, it's clean and assure reactivity :

```js
get toBeDisplayed(){
  const { someLogicState } = this.state;
  if(someLogicState)
    return (
      <div>
        Hi, world !
      </div>
    );
  else
    return null;
}

render(){
  return (<div>{this.toBeDisplayed}</div>);
}
```

Comment: clean? you go from js (the render fxn return statement) to html (the div) back to js (the referenced getter) back to html (the return value of the getter).

Answer (score 0):

I just create a method to take exprestion and two another arguments as the template in case the expression truth and the other is an option else template

```js
export function rif(exp, template, elseTemplate = null) {
    if (exp) {
        return template;
    } else {
        return elseTemplate;
    }
}
```

and I use it like this

```js
import { rif } from '../utilities';

...
render() {
        return (
            <main role="main" className="container">

                {rif(
                    this.movies.length > 0,
                    <p>Showing {this.movies.length} movies. </p>,
                    <p>There are no movies..</p>
                )}
            </main>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working both angular and react. I think `angular` nicely manage logical condition through different directives.

In `reactjs` this approach work different way.

You can use `if else` condition as `return` of `render function` or `ternary operator`.

> With if else

```
  render(){
    
    const auth = true;
    
    if(!auth)
      return(
      <div className="ps-checkout__login">
        <div className="d-flex flex-row">
            <div className="p-2"><img src="../../../static/img/return-customer.png"></img> 
             Returning Customer?</div>
            <div className="p-2"> 
                <Link href="/account/login">
                    <a>                            
                        Click here to login
                    </a>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  else return null;
    }
```

> With ternary operator

```
{ auth?
    (<div className="ps-checkout__login">
        <div className="d-flex flex-row">
            <div className="p-2"><img src="../../../static/img/return-customer.png"></img> 
            Returning Customer?</div>
            <div className="p-2"> 
                <Link href="/account/login">
                    <a>                            
                        Click here to login
                    </a>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>):null }
```