# Is there an equivalent for ng-show and ng-hide in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Is there an equivalent for `ng-show` and `ng-hide` in **react.js**?

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">
<div ng-show="myVar">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Welcome to my home.</p>
</div>
```

In **Angular** the above code works very well, but i'm trying to do this using react i'm not able to find an equivalent....

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally, it has worked after an hour of search using the conditional expression like this:

```
{!myVar && <div>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Welcome to my home.</p>
</div>}
```

Comment: SImpler is `{!myVar && <div>...`. Explicitly checking for `=== null`isn't a great way to code it

Comment: It can be a good option if we compare this with `ng-if` but if we focus on the nature of `ng-show` it hides and shows the component rather than re-rendering.

Comment: Cross-link to [this answer on `ng-if`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36771363/1175496). Shouldn't it be `!!myVar && <div>...`?

Answer (score 23):

Suggested solutions are actually "ng-if" equivalents of React. If you use ng-if and the state is false then the component won't appear in DOM. If you use ng-show/hide it will appear in DOM but it will be hidden in the browser.

In many cases `{myVar && <div />}` solution will work as expected but there might be cases where this is not the ideal solution. Because this will load/unload the component and not show/hide. For example; if you have tab container and you're using this to show/hide tab contents; depending on the selected tab, each time you will load/unload other contents. This might be an issue if you're using redux-form or similar approaches. Here you do need an ng-show kinda solution and not ng-if.

Since React does not have attribute directives, you either need to write an HOC or a wrapper component(element directive) that handles this. Or simply add a dynamic inline style like this:

```
<div style={{ display: myVar ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Welcome to my home.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 5):

Nothing is there in Reactjs like angular js to show and hide. Reactjs use to show the view. But you can use the ternary operator to full fill your requiremenet like this:-

```
{myVar ? <div>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Welcome to my home.</p>
</div> 
: null}
```

Comment: @ManikantaB no it won't, If the value is there then only it will show.If this answer is working and use full then you can mark the vote up for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking something even closer to Angular's ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if for React, rather than mixing JSX expressions with ES6 - which is less elegant, you might want to try out a module I have created - Tersus-jsx.macro.

Rather than doing this:

```
<div>
  {(a === 0) && (
    <button
      id="gotoA"
      className="link"
      onClick={clicking}
    />
  )}
</div>
```

You can now simply define a tj-if prop just like what we used to do in AngularJS:

```
<div>
  <button
    tj-if={a === 0}
    id="gotoA"
    className="link"
    onClick={clicking}
  />
</div>
```

Also thanks to the latest version of create-react-app now supports Babel-Macro out of the box. All needs to be done is npm install this module, wrap the render return with "tersus" and start assigning the props. This also supports ng-repeat/ng-(using tj-for) and can be mix-use with tj-if.

You can install this from:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tersus-jsx.macro

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires more code and creating a separate component.
But looks a little more tidy.

Put a component and pass the condition as prop

```
<MyVarContainer show={whateverCondition} />
```

And then the component itself:

```
function MyVarContainer (props){
    if (props.show){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>Welcome to my home</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return null
}
```

Notice that you don't need to put the Component in a separate file. So you don't need to export/import either.