# Hide Font Awesome icon component and display another based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a pomodoro timer with 4 sessions. When a 25-minute timer is up, 1 is added to a state variable `sessionNumber`. 
I have four of these circle/unchecked checkboxes displayed when the pomodoro cycle starts:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
  icon={faCircle}
  size="2x"
  className="pomodoro-unchecked session-checkbox"
/>
```

Each time 1 is added to `sessionNumber` state, I would like to hide one and display a different icon component:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
  icon={faCheckCircle}
  size="2x"
  className="pomodoro-checked session-checkbox"
/>
```

The only ways I could think of doing this would take a whole lot of code -- for example if statements based on each session number, like with an if statement, if the session is 0, display 4 unchecked circles (with the code for all four components), and if the session is 1, display 1 checked circle and 3 unchecked circles, and so forth. The second way I considered would be to give each one a different class name and in the method that changes the session number, display and hide each one, based on which session number it is (that would be more complicated). Is there a simpler, more succinct method?

Comment: I dont know react that well, but in angular js you can do things like ng-show="myVariable == 2".  Does react have the same notion ?

Comment: I think second choice seems to be good one. For implementation, you can use styled component as wrapper of those 4 icons and would need to render number of checked or unchecked ones with props. of course there are already classes defined to show or hide icons and it will be determined after checking the props value whether it is greater or less.

Comment: I would probably create 2 arrays of icons like timerIcons = ['icon1', 'icon2', 'icon3', 'icon4']; timerIconsChecked = ['icon1-checked', ...] and just use that with the logic as fengo said. That way, you can easily update the icons, even if FA renames them, or you add/remove steps b/c they're just strings.

Comment: @fengo Just to be sure, you're referring to Styled Components the package? (Hadn't heard of it before)

Comment: @Programnik unfortunately there's no equivalent of ng-show https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110799/is-there-an-equivalent-for-ng-show-and-ng-hide-in-react-js

Comment: Why dont you manipulate the class name. For example classname={`pomodoro-${session==1 ?'checked' : 'unchecked'} session-checkbox`}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array in `state`. You could initialise the array with four "faCircle" and then use the `array.fill()` method on setState to fill up the icons with "faCheckCircle". Then you can map over the array to render the appropriate icon.

```
class SessionIcons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sessions: 0,
      icons: ["faCircle", "faCircle", "faCircle", "faCircle"]
    };
  }

  onAddSession = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      sessions: state.sessions + 1,
      icons: state.icons.fill("faCheckCircle", 0, state.sessions + 1)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.icons.map((icon, index) => (
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            key={icon + index}
            icon={icon === "faCircle" ? faCircle : faCheckCircle}
            size="2x"
          />
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.onAddSession}>Add session</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-tdd-qzs1n

Comment: He wants to change icons not listing them.What you are doing is listing them.He doesn't need them that way.

Comment: I'm changing the rendered icon based on the number of sessions. The question says she starts with 4 unchecked circles and needs to change the circles to checked when sessions are incremented. Check my codesandbox, that's what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Timer extends React.Component{
  state = {  sessionNumber: 1}

 checkTimer = () =>{
..your logic to check timer every 25 mins
 this.setState({timerState:1})
  }
render(){
Let font;
if( this.state.sessionNumber == 1)
 {
    font = <FontAwesomeIcon
    icon={faCircle}
   size="2x"
   className="pomodoro-unchecked session-checkbox"
  />
 }
   else if(this.state.sessionNumber == 2)
   {      
    font = FontAwesomeIcon
  icon={faCheckCircle}
  size="2x"
  className="pomodoro-checked session-checkbox"
    />
   return(

        {font}


     )
    }
   }
```