# How do you render or not render table data based on conditions, using a loop in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabular

I'm doing an exercise using React.js and am having trouble iterating through a data array and selectively rendering elements based on the properties in each data node.

The dataset is formatted like this:

```
var requests =  [   
    {"id":1, "title":"request","updated":"2015-08-15","created":"2015-08-12","status":"Denied"}, ...]
```

My rendering code is looking for a flag value to determine what it should or should not be rendering. The logic is working fine (i.e. returning true or false when it should, a la console.log), but the rendering code, written in JSX, is giving me trouble. This is what I have so far in the tbody section:

```
           <tbody>    
             {requests.map(function(row, i) {
               {filter === requests[i].status || filter === "" ?
                 <tr key={i}>
                   <td style={tdStyle}>{row.title}</td>
                   <td style={tdStyle}>{row.status}</td>
                   <td style={tdStyle}>{row.created_at}</td>
                   <td style={tdStyle}>{row.updated_at}</td>
                   <td style={tdStyle}><a href="">delete</a></td>
                 </tr>
               : null}
             })}
           </tbody>
```

I have looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538638/how-to-have-conditional-elements-and-keep-dry-with-facebook-reacts-jsx) for guidance, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: be sure to return the jsx you are generating. Right now it isn't actually returning the result of your statement, just evaluating it and moving on.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. How would that look syntactically though? Would I use the `return ()` syntax around or inside of my conditional?

Comment: Inside. And for multiline condition statements, it is definitely best to use if...else syntax rather than the ternary operator.

Comment: if (...) { return (<jsx stuff > </jsx stuff>);} else { return ( whatever else)}

Comment: Okay! I've got the loop working well, but now when I re-render it isn't removing the unwanted elements from the DOM. Do I need to use set-state instead of calling the render()? Or should I explicitly hide those elements that don't meet the condition, in an else?

Comment: see my answer for using filter function along with map to only map the results that meet your condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const requests =  [
    {"id":1, "title":"Request from Nancy","updated_at":"2015-08-15 12:27:01 -0600","created_at":"2015-08-12 08:27:01 -0600","status":"Denied"},
    {"id":2, "title":"Request from David","updated_at":"2015-07-22 11:27:01 -0600","created_at":"2015-07-15 12:27:01 -0600","status":"Approved"}
];

const jsx = function(filter) {

    const isCorrectStatus = (x) => x.status === filter;

    return  <tbody>    
         {requests.filter(isCorrectStatus).map(function(row, i) {
           return <tr key={i}>
               <td>{row.title}</td>
               <td>{row.status}</td>
               <td>{row.created_at}</td>
               <td>{row.updated_at}</td>
               <td><a href="">delete</a></td>
             </tr>
        })}
    </tbody>
}

const filter = 'Denied';
ReactDOM.render(jsx(filter), document.getElementById('app'));
```

I'd rewrite it as follows, we have a prebuilt filter method, we may as well use it rather than reimplementing the wheel, and it keeps our code a little cleaner.

Comment: I find this answer compelling, but I'm totally new to React and am not sure how to incorporate this into my code. Could you have a look at my fiddle and give me a little more explanation on where to to put what and why? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Absolutely, give me a few minutes.

Comment: I've forked your fiddle, take a look at my changes here:https://jsfiddle.net/xnsb9g3p/1/.  I made a few changes, one important one being moving filter into state and removing your call to render, once you change state render is automatically called for you.  Let me know if you have any more questions about the changes made.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to go over it to understand exactly what's happening, particularly with the arrow syntax and the bind method, but this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you need to return the computed value, this allows the `map()` function to work properly.

Also, in this situation I would use the `filter()` function to only map through the elements that meet your condition.

```
<tbody>
  // use the filter function to get only the matching elements before mapping
  {requests.filter(function(row){
    // return true to include array element, false to exclude
    return (filter === row.status || filter === "");
  }).map(function(row, i) {
      // always wrap jsx in parentheses because of line breaks in javascript syntax
      // make sure to return, this actually adds it
      return (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td style={tdStyle}>{row.title}</td>
          <td style={tdStyle}>{row.status}</td>
          <td style={tdStyle}>{row.created_at}</td>
          <td style={tdStyle}>{row.updated_at}</td>
          <td style={tdStyle}><a href="">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
      );
  })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: This is what I have now, and it works great on the first pass, but when the filter flag changes and the render function is called again the DOM isn't updating to remove pre-existing unwanted elements based on the new value of the flag. What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: updated to use filter method before map to properly filter the results