# Component Mounting to validate url parameter before view rendering in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, api, validation, reactjs

In my [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) app, I need to validate a parameter `id` in the url and then render the view accordingly (i.e. different views in cases of successful and failed validation). Here's sample code:

**routes.js**

```
// just relevant lines of code:
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import Foo from '../containers/foo';

const AppRoutes = (
  <Route component={Base} path="/">
    <Route component={Foo} path="/url/:id"/>
  </Route>
);
export default AppRoutes;
```

**Class Foo**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { isValid } from '../service';    

class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    check : true
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    if (isValid(this.props.params.id) == false || 'undefined') {
      console.log(isValid(this.props.params.id));
      this.setState({
        check : false
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.check){
      return(...);
    }else{
      return(...);
    }
  };
}
export default Foo;
```

**service.js**

```
"use strict";
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

function fetchId(method, url, id, callback){
  var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);
  if (!xhr) return;
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", callback);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(query));
}

function isValid(id){
  let url = 'https://some/api/url/';
  return fetchId('POST', url, id, function(){
    return (this.readyState===4 && this.responseText.length>0) ? true : false;
  });
}
export default {isValid}
```

Now `console.log(isValid(this.props.params.id)` in `componentWillMount()` is always printing `undefined`, no matter `id` is valid or not. It seems there might be two issues, either I'm not properly returning boolean response of `isValid()` or I'm wrongly utilising `componentWillMount()`. I went thought the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) as well and came to know that `componentWillMount()` actually triggers before `render()`.

Can somebody please point out the real issue and correct me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is calling Foo? is params coming from react-router? if so can you show us how your routes are setup?

Comment: @JoPeyper I've updated the question by mentioning relevant lines of `routes.js`. Please feel free to ask if there's still something missing.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I'm not sure the rest of your `XMLHttpRequest` works as I've never worked with it directly over using libraries to manage it for me like fetch or axios.*

The issue is in your is valid method.

```
function isValid(id){
  let url = 'https://some/api/url/';
  return fetchId('POST', url, id, function(){
    return (this.readyState===4 && this.responseText.length>0) ? true : false;
  });
}
```

The issue is the return of the boolean is inside a function, and the `isValid` function is actually returning the result of the `fetchId` function (which doesn't return anything, therefore you are logging `undefined`).

**Why is this happening?**

Well, your request is executed in the background and doesn't block execution. So at the end of your `isValid` function, it doesn't have the boolean to return.

**What can you do about it?**

Your `isValid` function should take in a callback to delay its setting of state until the request is completed, similar to the `fetchId` function.

```
function isValid(id, callback){
  let url = 'https://some/api/url/';
  fetchId('POST', url, id, function(){
    callback(this.readyState===4 && this.responseText.length>0)
  });
}
```

and you call it like so

```
componentWillMount(){
  isValid(this.props.params.id, valid => {
    if (!valid) {
      console.log(isValid(this.props.params.id));
      this.setState({
        check : false
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**But I have callbacks inside callbacks and its all getting too hard to follow!**

You're not wrong. These kinds of interactions get very messy if you try and do them completely inside your react component. You can seperate your concerns of state management, actions and views quite easily using [redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Comment: at last some proper answer although these callbacks doesn't seem perfect option. I applied your changes with valid id and in response, it renders the right part but within a sec, it again prints `undefined` and re-renders the other part

Comment: Before condition `if (!valid)...`, I added `console.log(valid)` and it's printing `false` twice and `true` once. That means the function is running thrice, any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Possibly something else is causing the component to mount a few different times. Hard to tell without running and debugging it. To get this right, you really will want to look at redux. Redux will change the way you think about state in your component and make complicated loading states much easier.

Comment: try putting the `console.log` before the call to `isValid` in `componentWillMount` and see how often that gets called. Its either mounting multiple times or your callback is getting called multiple times by `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: okk. I was actually preferring to avoid redux at the moment. I'm gonna try some more things including replacing `XMLHttpRequest` with some library. hoping for something to work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to do some conditional rendering. I ran across this problem while learning react myself (Assuming this is what you are looking for). If so, then this is how you'd do it:

---

```
render(
<div>
     {this.state.isTrue ? ( 
                <div>if this.state.isTrue is true then render this!</div>
            ) : (
                <div>Else, render this! </div>
      )}
</div>
)
```

---

So, in the above code block, you could do some sort of condition check to see if this.props.params.id === 'some string' and then when it's true, it would render the first set of divs.

Message me if that doesn't work or you're looking for a different solution!

Comment: Also, what ids are you looking for in your route? Are you trying to do email validation?

Comment: I have updated rendering part for you. Please give it a look again, this is how I'm applying conditioning but I don't think its a conditioning issue here. The problem is that `console.log` in `componentWillMount()` is always printing `undefined` whereas it should be either `true` or `false`.

Regarding validation, nope its just a random (sort of product) id validation

Comment: also the ternary conditioning solution you mentioned is just for one line to return/render. There are many other threads out there for [conditional rendering in react](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538638/how-to-have-conditional-elements-and-keep-dry-with-facebook-reacts-jsx)

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what is calling the Foo component.
But it looks like you are missing a constructor in class `Foo`.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { check : true };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props.params.id);
  }
  render() {
      //...
  }
}
```

See [React State Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) for more.

Comment: doesn't seems helpful. Also it would be `this.state` in constructor as just state will generate `undefined` error

Comment: Thanks I fixed to say `this.state`