# How do I set a condition from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements

In my react component

```
render() {
let hasTask = this.props.task

return <div>
 {hasTask && <div> I have a task </div>}
</div>
 }
```

Works perfectly fine, except when the props doesn't have a task. what is the best way to handles this in react.

the problem: The page does not render because hasTask can't be set because there is no props called task.

I am really sorry for the simple question. I have to start from somewhere.

Comment: Why doesnt it work fine then?

Comment: what is the problem if props doesn't have task?

Comment: What you've shown works just fine without a task ([proof](https://jsfiddle.net/3j5o7d69/)): Nothing is rendered for the component, which is what you've asked for. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: if it doesnt have task, the page breaks. because there is no props in task

Comment: @EmbetIsit: Not with the above. See my comment (and proof) above. If there's no `task` on `this.props`, `this.props.task` yields `undefined`, which is falsy, so `hasTask && <div>...</div>` results in `undefined`, which React takes to mean "don't render anything."

Comment: updated, ^^ that the just of what i am trying to solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538638/how-to-have-conditional-elements-and-keep-dry-with-facebook-reacts-jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The page does not render because hasTask can't be set because there is no props called task.

I think what you're trying to ask is: How do I render something *else* if there's no `this.props.task`? Because what you have works just fine when there's no `this.props.task`:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let hasTask = this.props.task

    return <div>
      {hasTask && <div> I have a task </div>}
      </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
    Example without task:
    <Example />
    Example with task:
    <Example task="foo" />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

If so, the answer is that people commonly use a conditional operator:

```
return <div>
  {hasTask ? <div> I have a task </div> : <div> I don't have a task </div> }
  </div>;
```

Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let hasTask = this.props.task

    return <div>
      {hasTask ? <div> I have a task </div> : <div> I don't have a task </div> }
      </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
    Example without task:
    <Example />
    Example with task:
    <Example task="foo" />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

If you want a `div` both times, you can simplify that a bit:

```
return <div>{hasTask ? "I have a task" : "I don't have a task"}</div>;
```

Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let hasTask = this.props.task

    return <div>{hasTask ? "I have a task" : "I don't have a task"}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
    Example without task:
    <Example />
    Example with task:
    <Example task="foo" />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Should have been closed as a duplicate and before that as unclear.

Comment: @MuratK.: I did in fact vote as unclear. Good dupe, goes on my list. I'll go ahead and leave this for now (it's going to get closed and deleted anyway).

Answer (score -1):

```
render(
 let hasTask = this.props.task
 return (<div>{hasTask? <div>I have a task</div>:<div/>}</div>)
)
```

Comment: if breaks if there is no task.. let hasTask = this.props.task

Comment: @EmbetIsit It won't break. It will be undefined. If `this.props.task` is not there then `hasTask` will have a value undefined