# How to display react numerical props only if they pass from the container?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I have two different containers that call `ControlSection` component. One pass `bestScore` prop and the second pass `level` prop.

In the `ControlSection` component I want to display the prop in `<h2>` only if they pass from the container. How can I do it?

```
const ControlSection = ({ score, bestScore, level }) => {
    return (
        <div className='controlSection'>
        <div className='gameStatistics'>
            <h2>Score: {score}</h2>
            {bestScore ? <h2>Best: {bestScore}</h2>}
            {level ? <h2>Level: {level}</h2>}
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If bestScore or level is 0, it will not render anything, because 0 is falsy. Be aware of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have conditional elements and keep DRY with Facebook React's JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538638/how-to-have-conditional-elements-and-keep-dry-with-facebook-reacts-jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is Conditional Rendering and the standard way to render a component when the prop is defined is by using the && operator.

`{bestScore && <h2>Best: {bestScore}</h2>}`

The second part, `<h2>Best: {bestScore}</h2>`, will only be rendered if `bestScore` is true. (you could use any other condition here)

This is because in JS, `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `''` and `NaN` are evaluated as false (falsy).

`false && <h1>something</h1>` will be evaluated as false, therefore it won't be rendered.

Coming back to the bestScore prop, it could also be 0 and evaluated as falsy. You need to take care of that. Something like this could work:

`{(bestScore || bestScore === 0) && <h2>Best: {bestScore}</h2>}`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your case is the following to cover your requirement:

```
const ControlSection = ({ score, bestScore, level }) => {
    return (
        <div className='controlSection'>
           <div className='gameStatistics'>
              <h2>Score: {score}</h2>
                 {bestScore != null ? <h2>Best: {bestScore}</h2> : null}
                 {level != null ? <h2>Level: {level}</h2> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

By doing `bestScore != null` the code identifies 2 different things as `false` which are `null` and `undefined`. Please refer to the following code example:

```js
let bestScore = null;
console.log('testing for null value:', bestScore != null);

bestScore = undefined;
console.log('testing for undefined value:', bestScore != null);

bestScore = '';
console.log('testing for \'\' value:', bestScore != null);

bestScore = 0;
console.log('testing for 0 value:', bestScore != null);
```

In `false` value case the `h2` tag won't be rendered in your component thus you have covered 2 cases where you have either `undefined` or `null` value from properties.

To handle 0 and '' values you might want to do the following:

```js
function hasToRender(value) {
    if (value === '') {
        return false;
    } else if (value == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (value != null) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

console.log('null', hasToRender(null));
console.log('undefined', hasToRender(undefined));
console.log('\'\'', hasToRender(''));
console.log(0, hasToRender(0));
console.log(17, hasToRender(17));
```

So I think the working solution would be the following in your case to cover all the cases:

```
const ControlSection = ({ score, bestScore, level }) => {
    function hasToRender(value) {
        if (value === '') {
            return false;
        } else if (value == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (value != null) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return (
        <div className='controlSection'>
        <div className='gameStatistics'>
            <h2>Score: {score}</h2>
                {hasToRender(bestScore) ? <h2>Best: {bestScore}</h2> : null}
                {hasToRender(level) ? <h2>Level: {level}</h2> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Of course the hasToRender function can be simplified further but this gives you the idea, hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

`{typeof bestScore !== 'undefined' && <h2>Best: {bestScore}</h2>}`

or

`{typeof level === 'number' && <h2>Level: {level}</h2>}`