# Add `if` condition in gatsby jsx

Tags: reactjs, markdown, jsx, gatsby

I want to add  elements in gatsby template file in some cases.

I am developing document site using gatsby, the document made by markdown file.
Here is md files, and gatsby template. How can I add  elements if the document has **pinned=true** condition??

#### markdown

```
---
title: "doc title"
date: "2020-06-01"
tags: ["some","tags"]
pinned: TRUE
---

document body.
```

#### template file

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export default class DocsList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const posts = this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
    return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(({ node }) => {
        const title = node.frontmatter.title || node.fields.slug
        const tags = node.frontmatter.tags || node.fields.slug
        const ispinned = node.frontmatter.pinned || node.fields.slug
        return(
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p>{(tags || []).map(tags => (<span className="tags" key={tags}><FaHashtag />{tags}</span>))}</p>

        // if the document has `pinned=true` attribute, show <span> tag below
        <p>{if {ispinned===true ? `<span>This is PINNED item</span>` }}</p>
        )
        })}
    </div>
        )
    }
}

export const query = graphql`
query docssListQuery($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
  allMarkdownRemark(
    filter: {
      fields: { collection: { eq: "manuals" } }
      frontmatter: { published: { ne: false } }
    }
    sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
    limit: $limit
    skip: $skip
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        fields {
          slug
        }
        frontmatter {
          title
          date
          tags
          pinned
        }
        excerpt
        timeToRead
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have conditional elements and keep DRY with Facebook React's JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538638/how-to-have-conditional-elements-and-keep-dry-with-facebook-reacts-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <p>{isPinned && <span>This is PINNED item</span>}</p>
```

If `isPinned` evaluates to `true`, and since `<span />` is truthy, then the value of the whole expression would be this `span`, hence your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for quick anwser. i applied this, but the <span> was displayed on Every document. I have both md docs, which has `pinned` attributes true and false. And graphql result is responding collectlly.

Comment: I tried `console.log(isPinned)` and out put is below 

---
/manuals/faq/ <- This is value of slug
true
/manuals/overview/ <- This is value of slug
---

Answer (score 1):

You should use conditional rendering. Change your code:

```
// if the document has `pinned=true` attribute, show <span> tag below
<p>{if {ispinned===true ? `<span>This is PINNED item</span>` }}</p>
```

to

```
// if the document has `pinned=true` attribute, show <span> tag below
<p>{ispinned ? `<span>This is PINNED item</span>`: null }</p>
```